# Merge (2+) Multi Index Pandas DFs on common Indexes (with some DFs missing a few Indexes) - Efficiently

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge, concatenation

We need to merge multiple pandas multi-index Dataframes.

The **catch** is that, **some have fewer indexes than the others**. The same value needs to be broadcast for all cases of missing indexes (as shown in the screenshot)

Since the frames will be huge (upto 10M rows)  with upto 8 index levels, and some to be merged will have only 2-3 of those, I need it to be **efficient**. I was wondering what's a good way to accomplish this.

#### **DF1**

| index1 | index2 | index3 | val1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 21 | 31 | 100 |
|  |  | 32 | 101 |
| 12 | 22 | 33 | 102 |
|  |  | 34 | 103 |

#### **DF2**

| index1 | index2 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 21 | 200 |
| 12 | 22 | 300 |

#### **DF1 merge DF2**

| index1 | index2 | index3 | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 21 | 31 | 100 | 200 |
|  |  | 32 | 101 | 200 |
| 12 | 22 | 33 | 102 | 300 |
|  |  | 34 | 103 | 300 |

I've tried using traditional pd.merge, pd.join, pd.concat, but they're quite slow for my data, taking several minutes for larger frames. Since this needs to be repeated frequently, I can't afford this time. They should be sorted in the same way, so I don't need to sort by index.

Comment: Simply `df1.join(df2)`, if efficiency is limiting then pandas might not be suited for your application

Comment: Is the CPU the limiting factor? If so, you can think about splitting your df1 into separate pieces. Then use python's multiprocessing library and merge the results afterwards.